# Java: Add Elements to a Panel from an different method

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe, windowbuilder

I created a Window with the Windowbuilder of eclipse. the window contains a content panel and two scroll panels within the content panel. I want to add elements to the two scroll panels out of a different method. My code looks like this(just the relevant parts):

```
public window() {
  contentPane = new JPanel(); // Plus some methods like setLayout or setBorder for the    contentpane

   JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
   contentPane.add(scrollPane1);  

   JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
   contentPane.add(scrollPane2);  
}

public static void addItems(ArrayList<String> list)
{
    Window w = new Window();

    for(String s : list)
    {
       w.contentPane.scrollPane1.addElement(s);
    /* Normally it should be something like this, but I just get access 
    to the contentPane and cannot add anything directly to the ScrollPanes. */      
    }
}
```

Is there any special setting that denies to access the single components directly?

edit: Thanks to @summerbulb I made some changes to the `addItems`-Method, it now looks like this.

```
    public static void addItems(ArrayList<String> appList)
{
    WindowAppsAndHardware w = new WindowAppsAndHardware();
    Component[] components = w.contentPane.getComponents(); 
    Component component = null; 

    for(String s : appList)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) 
    { 
       component = components[i]; 
       if (component.getName().equals("scrollPane1")); 
       { 
         Label lbl = new Label();
         lbl.setName(s);
         component.addElement(lbl); 
         /*Here I want to add the Label to the component,
         but component dont have the `addElement`-Method.*/
       } 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your initial though might look intuitive, when you think of it, it can't be true.

`w.contentPane` works fine, as `Window` is your class and `contentPane` is a member of that class. But `contentPane.add(scrollPane1);` does not add `scrollPane1` as a member of `contentPane`.

What you need is:

```
Component[] components = w.contentPane.getComponents(); 
Component component = null; 
for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) 
{ 
   component = components[i]; 
   if (component == scrolPane1) 
   { 
      component.addElement(s);
   } 
}
```

**EDIT:** (After OP edited his question)
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150437/416300) states (based on the [JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)) that you're not supposed to add elements to the `JScrollPane`. Instead, you should do:

```
JPanel view = (JPanel)scrollPane.getViewPort().getView();
view.addItem(s);
```

Comment: thanks for your input. In fact the only thing I wrote is the `addItems`-method. `window()` is completely autogenerated, after I designed the window with the Windowbuilder-Plugin. So i guess its not wrong to use `contentPane.add(scrollPane1)`.

Comment: @Alika87 `contentPane.add(scrollPane1)` is the correct way to add an item, but it does not add `scrollPane1` as a class member of `contentPane`, it just adds `scrollPane1` to its component collection, so `contentPane.scrollPane1` is not valid.

Comment: `scrollPane1` is a **local** variable in the constructor.  I believe `component == scrolPane1` won't work.

Comment: @PM77-1 You're right, of course, sorry for missing that. `scrollPane1` has to be extracted as a local variable. But then you can just give up all the loop and call `scrollPane1.add(s)`. If you don't want to do that, I suggest you give your panel a unique id and change the condition to test the id.

Comment: `if (component == scrolPane1)` wont work I changed it in `if (component.getName().equals("scrollPane1"))`. There is one flaw now, component dont have an addElement-method. I edit the question and add the made changes.

Comment: @summerbulb the SO-question in your edit contains really good information, thanks for that. I will try it and give feedback, if its working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as I have not done this before, but it looks like you are trying to access the contentPane on the window, but there is no where in your code that you are attaching the contentPane to the window, so that is why you would not be able to access it's children.

Comment: contentPane is a member of window.