# How add jasper report viewer to a scrollpanel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

this is my code ..

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            Connection con= DB_Connection.getConnection();

            String REPORT="C:\\Users\\Harshana\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Remedco\\src\\Reports\\report1.jrxml";

            JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(REPORT);   
            JasperPrint jp= JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
            JasperViewer viewer=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
            Container container = viewer.getContentPane();
            jScrolReprt.add(container);
            jScrolReprt.revalidate();
            jScrolReprt.repaint();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPatient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPatient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPatient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it to viewport no to the JScrollPane directly

See
[jScrollPane can't add component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149608/jscrollpane-cant-add-component)

and

[this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddcomponenttoJScrollPane.htm)