# Add a button to JScrollPane - Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

I have this `Frame` class; as you can see I added a `splitPane` to my `Frame` class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int X_AXIS = 175;
    private static final int Y_AXIS = 25;
    private static final int WIDTH= 930;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private SplitPane splitPane;

    public Frame() {

        this.setTitle("My Frame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(X_AXIS,Y_AXIS,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        splitPane = new SplitPane();
        this.getContentPane().add(splitPane);   
    }

}
```

This is `SplitPane` class. I added a `JScrollPane` on the left:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SplitPane extends JSplitPane{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int SPLIT_WEIGHT  = 250;
    private JScrollPane leftPanel;

    public SplitPane() {

        leftPanel = new LeftPanel();
        this.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        this.setDividerLocation(SPLIT_WEIGHT);
        this.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
    }
}
```

Finally this is `LeftPanel` class:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout;

public class LeftPanel extends JScrollPane{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LeftPanel() {    

        this.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Hello World!");
        this.add(button);   
    }

}
```

The button does not appear.
What can I do to make visible my button `"Hello World!"`?

Comment: You probably don't want to add the `button` directly to the `JScrollPane`. Call `this.setViewportView(button);` instead. (Or preferably use a `JPanel` containing the button as the argument)

Comment: It works, thank you. I thought JScrollPane was just a scrollable JPanel, but I was wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jScrollPane can't add component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149608/jscrollpane-cant-add-component)