# Is it possible to create an Array of JTables in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

What I am trying to create is a java page containing multiple JTables with same model but the content of these models is different.
now the total number of jtables required is not known at the time of programming and i want to create multiple instances of table,
for which i am trying to create an array of DefaultTableModel, then an Array of Jtable and Finally an Array of JScrollPane.
when Attaching the model to the table and then attaching the table in  the scrollpane ,the table is not appearing neither any error is occurring.

Thanks in Advance!

```
private void showComponents() {

    lbl = new JLabel[users.size()];
    tbl = new JTable[users.size()];
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel[users.size()];
    sp = new JScrollPane[users.size()];

    for(int i =0;i<users.size();i++){
        lbl[i] = new JLabel(users.get(i));
        jPanel2.add(lbl[i]);
        dtm[i] = new DefaultTableModel(column,0){
                    @Override
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                    }
                };
        for(int j = 0;j<object.size();j++)
        {
            if(users.get(i).equals(object.get(j).getUser())){
                String code = object.get(j).getCompCode();
                String info = object.get(j).getInfo();
                Integer amount = object.get(j).getAmount();
                Boolean paid = object.get(j).getAmountPaid();

                Object[] data ={object.get(j).getUser(),code,info,amount,paid}; 
                System.out.println("data is :"+object.get(j).getService()+","+code+","+info+","+amount+","+paid+",::::"+object.get(j).getUser());

                dtm[i].addRow(data);
            }
        }
        tbl[i] = new JTable();
        tbl[i].setModel(dtm[i]);
        sp[i] = new JScrollPane();
        sp[i].setBackground(Color.red);
        sp[i].add(tbl[i]);
        jPanel2.add(sp[i]);
    }

    setVisible(true);        
}
```

here the users and object  are two arraylist containing some data.And all the other components like JLabel, JPanel have already been defined.

Comment: provide reason before you do downvote

Comment: i Agree , the user atleast intimidate me why he/she downvoted

Comment: I did not downvote, but this question is too broad. First of all answer to `Is it possible to create an Array of JTables in Java?` is yes, why not. But you do not provide any code so reasons for your table not showing up are endless from our point of view. Please ask question with [MCVE]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok no problem, but you could have requested for the code in the comment section..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a `TableModel` with a no column :

```
dtm[i] = new DefaultTableModel(column,0)
```

The [constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28int,%20int%29) state the parameters are in the opposite order

> public DefaultTableModel(int rowCount, int columnCount)

So simply use :

```
dtm[i] = new DefaultTableModel(0,column)
```

Here is the method after some changes to be usable, I've simply used some parameters and have changed the data passed (because you didn't provide anything to reproduced this).

```
private void showComponents(List<String> users, Object[][] object) {

    lbl = new JLabel[users.size()];
    tbl = new JTable[users.size()];
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel[users.size()];
    sp = new JScrollPane[users.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        //Label
        lbl[i] = new JLabel(users.get(i));

        //Data
        dtm[i] = new DefaultTableModel(0, 2);
        for (int j = 0; j < object.length; j++) {
            Object[] data = object[j];
            dtm[i].addRow(data);
        }

        //Table
        tbl[i] = new JTable(dtm[i]);

        //Pane
        sp[i] = new JScrollPane(tbl[i]);
        sp[i].setBackground(Color.red);

        //Add components to panel
        jPanel2.add(lbl[i]);
        jPanel2.add(sp[i]);
    }

    setVisible(true);
}
```

And the result (with a basic JPanel) for two users ("A" and "B") with the same data :

[image]

Also, don't add the component to the JScrollPane like this, instanciate with the JTable or add it to the viewport :

```
sp[i].getViewPort().add(tbl[i]);
```

Source : [MadProgrammer - jScrollPane can't add component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150437/4391450)

Comment: let me try without thescrollpanes.

Comment: @anshul Well you have a problem because I have added the screen showned by my code ... provide a [mcve]  if you want more help!

Comment: scrollpane actually allows me to contain the table within a specified area.

Comment: @Anshul check my edit about the scroll pane. I was using the constructor in my solution, so this was not a problem

Comment: @axelhhanks for the advice about the new JScrollPane(tbl[i]),

Answer (score 0):

After a struggle, I got your code to work.

I tried your:  `sp[i].getViewPort().add(tbl[i]);`

and got: undefined for type JScrollPane.

I tried:  `sp[i].getViewport().add(tbl[i]);`

and got:  NPE

When it worked, each JTable was about 400x400 px. 
I specified a 600x300 JFrame, and could only see 
JLabel #1, the top 2/3 of JTable #1, and JLabel #2.
Stretching the window vertically showed JTable #2.
I had no RED pixels.

THANK YOU for showing an array of JTable!